# Pyspark - Flattening Parquet containing an array of struct type along with other stnadard columns

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to read a parquet file into a dataframe, following schema:

```
root
 |-- TID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Resources: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- RId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- RVal: double (nullable = true)
```

where basically **Resources** is an *array* of *struct*
Here's how data looks like:

| TID | EID | Resources |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "T1" | "E1" | [{"a",10},{"b",20},{"c",30}] |
| "T2" | "E2" | [{"d",0},{"e",0.2}] |

Here's how the data should eventually look like after flattening (*kind of a explode and cross join of the values in **Resources***)

Note:Since **T1** and **E1** had **3** structs in the **Resources**, hence it should create 3 rows, each with values in Resources spit into columns.

| TID | EID | RId | RVal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "T1" | "E1" | "a" | 10 |
| "T1" | "E1" | "b" | 20 |
| "T1" | "E1" | "c" | 30 |
| "T2" | "E2" | "d" | 0 |
| "T2" | "E2" | "e" | 0.2 |

Such that final schema looks like:

```
root
 |-- TID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- RId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- RVal: double (nullable = true)
```

Here are some code snippets I tried out:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df =spark.read.parquet(file)

output_df = df.withColumn("RId", col("Resources")[0]).withColumn("RVal", col("Resources")[1]).drop("Resources")
```

But it's simply taking out the 1st and 2nd struct from **Resources** array, not really splitting the value, something like this:

| TID | EID | RId | RVal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "T1" | "E1" | {"a",10} | {"b",20} |

Another code I tried:

```
output_df = df.withColumn("RId", col("Resources")[0].val).withColumn("RVal", col("Resources")[1].val).drop("Resources")
```

But fails with error around **val**.

Could someone in community help me out of this problem and help me in getting the desired results, please?

Comment: are you using AWS or azure databricks?

Comment: This is on Azure - Synapse Analytics

Answer (score 0):

Let us use `inline` to explode array of structs into rows and columns

```
result = df.select('TID', "EID", F.inline('Resources'))
```

---

```
+---+---+---+----+
|TID|EID|RId|RVal|
+---+---+---+----+
| T1| E1|  a|10.0|
| T1| E1|  b|20.0|
| T1| E1|  c|30.0|
| T2| E2|  d| 0.0|
| T2| E2|  e| 0.2|
+---+---+---+----+
```

Comment: Thanks! Its not working for me. I imported - "from pyspark.sql import functions as F" and I am getting following error - module 'pyspark.sql.functions' has no attribute 'inline'.
Can you tell me what import is expected here?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution as follows-

```
exploded_df = df.withColumn("exploded_resources", explode("Resources"))

# Select the necessary columns
output_df = exploded_df.select(
    "TID",
    "EID",
    "exploded_resources.RId",
    "exploded_resources.RVal"
).withColumnRenamed("RId", "RId").withColumnRenamed("RVal", "RVal")
```